# How to implement Auto Layout with Button Animations

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, autolayout

I have an animation that moves three buttons upward on the screen programmatically. However, when I test it on the simulator for iPhone 6 or 4 the position of the buttons are all wrong (but are only right on the iPhone 5). How do I fix this. The buttons are built programmatically so I can't really use auto layout to position them on the view controller.

```
 -(IBAction)Search:(id)sender {

self.button.frame = CGRectMake(124, 475, 78, 72);

self.buttonTwo.frame = CGRectMake(124, 475, 78, 76);

self.buttonThree.frame = CGRectMake(124, 475, 78, 76);

// animate
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.75 animations:^{
    self.button.frame = CGRectMake(13, 403, 78, 72);
    self.buttonTwo.frame = CGRectMake(124, 347, 78, 76);
    self.buttonThree.frame = CGRectMake(232, 403, 78, 76);
```

Comment: why can't you use autolayout? you can still position them even if its programmatically created. you can create instance of NSLayoutConstraints.

Answer (score 0):

You are using fixed values for frames, but the screens are different widths and/or heights.

If they are correct for iPhone 5-5s (Also known as iPhone 4") then one way to handle it is:

```
-(IBAction)Search:(id)sender {

CGFloat screenWidth = self.view.bounds.size.width;
CGFloat screenHeight = self.view.bounds.size.height;

CGFloat normalizedX = (124 / 320) // You calculate these 'normalized' numbers, possibly from a designer's spec. 
                                  // it's the percent the amount should be over, as number from 0-1. 
                                  // This number is based on screen width of 320 having x 124 pt. 

CGFloat startingX = normalizedX * screenWidth;
CGFloat startingY = (475 / 588) * screenHeight;
CGFloat width = (78 / 320) * screenWidth;
CGFloat height = (72 / 588) * screenHeight;

CGRect startingRect = CGRectMake(startingX, startingY, width, height)

self.button.frame = startingRect;
self.buttonTwo.frame = startingRect;
self.buttonThree.frame = startingRect;

// animate
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.75 animations:^{
    CGFloat firstX = (13 / 320) * screenWidth;
    CGFloat lowerY = (403 / 588) * screenHeight;
    self.button.frame = CGRectMake(firstX, lowerY, width, height);

    CGFloat secondX = (124 / 320) * screenWidth;
    CGFloat upperY = (347 / 588) * screenHeight;
    self.buttonTwo.frame = CGRectMake(secondX, upperY, width, height);

    CGFloat thirdX = (233 / 320) * ScreenWidth;
    self.buttonThree.frame = CGRectMake(thirdX, lowerY, width, height);
}];
}
```

This will scale the size of everything up and keep the relative positions. Note UIButtons will have the same text size. You can play with these numbers until you get the effect you want. Hope this helps!

Comment: I need this in Objective-C. Thanks!

Comment: It's the same code, just minor syntax changes. Done.